# Heroku Generated DNS Target

Tags: heroku

I was generating a DNS target for a custom domain on Heroku.
Now I try to reach the generated DNS target with a ping? It doesn't work for me.
But should this work?

The reason why I tried it, I wasn't able to reach the the domain.
(But the http web page was reachable, only chrome was looking for the https web page.)

Answer (score 0):

No, the generated DNS target is not reachable, even after the domain is reachable.